# What's the best way to handle models and relationships in differents files with Sequelizer?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new in Sequelizer and I'had read the documentation. I have 3 tables in postgresql:

1) User.
2) UserHasPermissions.
3) Permission.

In these tables I have relationships between User - UserHasPermissions and UserHasPermissions - Permission

I wrote the connection file (db.js)

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize('example', 'postgres', 'none', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    }
})

const db = {}
db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

I wrote the models...

User.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('./database/db.js')
var Permission = require('./Permission')
var UserHasPermissions = require('./UserHasPermissions')

const User = db.sequelize.define('users', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true,
            notEmpty: true
        }
  },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    fullname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING({length: 100}),
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
    },
    phone: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING({length: 10}),
        validate: {
            isNumeric: true,
            notEmpty: true,
            len: [9,10]
        }
    },
    birthdate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
    },
    address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING({length: 200})
    },
    status: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING({length: 5})
    }
},
{
    schema: 'configuration',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true
})

UserHasPermissions.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(UserHasPermissions)

db.sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Tables created.')
   })
```

Permission.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('./database/db.js')

const Permission = db.sequelize.define('permission', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING({length: 100}),
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
  },
  description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING({length: 100}),
        validate: {
            notEmpty: true
        }
  }
},
{
    schema: 'configuration',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true
})

UserHasPermissions.belongsTo(Permission)
Permission.hasMany(UserHasPermissions)

module.exports = Permission
```

And the UserHasPermissions.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('./database/db.js')

const UserHasPermissions = db.sequelize.define('user_has_permissions', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
  }
},
{
    schema: 'configuration',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true
})

module.exports = UserHasPermissions
```

Ok. Three models for three tables in database.
Now relationships...

As you can see, I wrote relationships in User.js and Permission.js and in User.js I sync all models. Tables are created with relationships.

It works in database but I want to test all models.

Sequelize's documentation says if I use belongsTo() or hasMany(), sequelize creates accessor (getters and setters) automatically but in this scenario when I want to use a getter method in a controller file I got "method is not a function"

```
modelUser.findOne({
            where: {
            id: req.params.id
        })
        .then(user => user.getUserHasPermissions())
        .then(detail => console.log(detail.id))
```

I can't access to user.getUserHasPermissions() but, when I used "belongsTo" or "hasMany" sequelize has to create that methods

What can I do? I'm stuck here. Plese, help me!

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)